# How to fix some pandas column values with a dictionary and leave the others?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I need to fix a few values in dataframe column with some other values, I created a dictionary:

```
value2fixed= {"lala" : "dada", "howdy": "hoodie"}
```

and my dateframe `df` looks something like:

```
      col_1     col_2
0     lala      500
1     mel       650
2     howdy     750
```

in col_1 I want to replace `lala` with `dada` and `howdy` with `hoodie` leaving `mel` just being `mel`. I was hoping to use `df[col_1].map(value2fixed, na_action=None | 'ignore')` but both na_action option values replace `mel` with `NaN`.

Within a dictionary I can use `value2fixed.get(key, key)` and I was hoping to use somethin equal inside the `map` functionality (without using a lambda), preferably with `inplace=True`.Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard choice to pick the "best answer". All well and the last answer (overriding dict behaviour) really provided some new insight. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace with a nested dictionary:

```
df.replace({'col_1':value2fixed}, inplace=True)

>>> df
    col_1  col_2
0    dada    500
1     mel    650
2  hoodie    750
```

The nested dictionary syntax reads as:

> Nested dictionaries, e.g., {‘a’: {‘b’: nan}}, are read as follows: look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it with nan.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: Does it make much sense? It returns a copy of the entire dataframe, even though it's only one column you're modifying.

Comment: (see edit), True, no need to re-assign or copy, but the nested dictionary syntax with `inplace=True` still makes sense (I *think*)

Answer (score 4):

When `map` isn't an option, there's always `replace`;

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].replace(value2fixed)
df
    col_1  col_2
0    dada    500
1     mel    650
2  hoodie    750
```

The difference between `map` and `replace` is that `map` replaces "invalid" keys with NaNs - in contrast, `replace` does not touch them.

Answer (score 3):

You could also create a new dictionary class to instead pass the key if it's missing.

```
class SmartDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

df.col_1.map(SmartDict(value2fixed))

#0      dada
#1       mel
#2    hoodie
#Name: col_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I like this answer

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks! I mostly use stuff like this to return False when the key isn't in the dictionary since `bool(np.NaN)==True`, which is typically opposite behavior I want when mapping a column and then typecasting to bool.

Comment: Thanks for this insight!